# Reflections on Repulsiveness

Tags: meditation-recommendation

I am wondering if [this website](http://32parts.com/practice.html), and in particular, the guided audio meditations, are in line with the actual teaching of the 32 parts of the body meditation. I don't know much about it, so I thought I'd get a second opinion here, and also I thought that provided this is a good resource, I would at the same time share it with you all :)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for sharing the resource.

The complete guide of meditation is given in "[Mahāsatipaṭṭhāna Sutta](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/sutta/digha/dn22.html#1)" DN 22 (D ii 290) in pali thipitaka .
In this sutta the whole meditation topics are group in four main categories.

I. Kāyānupassanā     - Observation of Kāya
II. Vedanānupassanā -  Observation of Vedanā
III. Cittānupassanā  - Observation of Citta
IV. Dhammānupassanā -  Observation of Dhammas.

The "Kāyānupassanā " section has 6 sub sections.

A. Ānāpāna Pabba              - Section on ānāpāna
   B. Iriyāpatha Pabba           - Section on postures
   C. Sampajāna Pabba            - Section on sampajañña
   D. Paṭikūlamanasikāra Pabba   - Section on repulsiveness
   E. Dhātumanasikāra Pabba      - Section on the Elements
   F. Navasivathika Pabba        - Section on the nine charnel grounds

The 32 part body meditation is relate to section D.E.& F.-

**To get a idea some extracts are shown bellow. but it is recommend to read from beginning.**

... Furthermore, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu considers this very body, from the soles of the feet up and from the hair on the head down, which is delimited by its skin and full of various kinds of impurities: "In this kāya, there are the hairs of the head, hairs of the body, nails, teeth, skin, flesh, tendons, bones, bone marrow, kidneys, heart, liver, pleura, spleen, lungs, intestines, mesentery, stomach with its contents, feces, bile, phlegm, pus, blood, sweat, fat, tears, grease, saliva, nasal mucus, synovial fluid and urine."

...Just as if, bhikkhus, there was a bag having two openings and filled with various kinds of grain,.....

Furthermore, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu reflects on this very kāya, however it is placed, however it is disposed: "In this kāya, there is the earth element, the water element, the fire element and the air element."  ...

Furthermore, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu, just as if he was seeing a dead body, cast away in a charnel ground, one day dead, or two days dead or three days dead, swollen, bluish and festering, he considers this very kāya: "This kāya also is of such a nature, it is going to become like this, and is not free from such a condition ...

> **The method of practicing is given as .**.     Thus he dwells observing kāya in kāya internally, or he dwells observing kāya in kāya
>   externally, or he dwells observing kāya in kāya internally and
>   externally; he dwells observing the samudaya of phenomena in kāya, or
>   he dwells observing the passing away of phenomena in kāya, or he
>   dwells observing the samudaya and passing away of phenomena in kāya;
>   or else, [realizing:] "this is kāya!" sati is present in him, just to
>   the extent of mere ñāṇa and mere paṭissati, he dwells detached, and
>   does not cling to anything in the world. Thus, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu
>   dwells observing kāya in kāya.